# log4j2 Loki Appender on Databricks pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j, databricks, log4j2

I'm trying to send logs from my Databricks cluster to a Loki instance [using this appender](https://github.com/tkowalcz/tjahzi/blob/master/log4j2-appender/README.md).

1. I added an [init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) (see below) which modifies the `log4j2.xml` files for driver and executor.
2. I added a library in the libraries tab of cluster configuration. Added as a maven library. I can see in logs that it was successfully downloaded and installed.
3. Did `echo "" >> log4j2.xml` and waited 30 seconds for it to reread the config. Same error.

[image]

###### init script

```bash
for f in /databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/executor/log4j2.xml /databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/driver/log4j2.xml; do
  sed -i 's/<Configuration /<Configuration monitorInterval="30" /' "$f"
  sed -i 's/packages="com.databricks.logging"/packages="pl.tkowalcz.tjahzi.log4j2, com.databricks.logging"/'  "$f"
  sed -i 's~<Appenders>~<Appenders>\n    <Loki name="Loki" bufferSizeMegabytes="64">\n      <host>loki.atops.abc.com</host>\n      <port>3100</port>\n\n      <ThresholdFilter level="ALL"/>\n      <PatternLayout>\n        <Pattern>%X{tid} [%t] %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n%exception{full}</Pattern>\n      </PatternLayout>\n\n      <Header name="X-Scope-OrgID" value="ABC"/>\n      <Label name="server" value="Databricks"/>\n      <Label name="foo" value="bar"/>\n      <Label name="system" value="abc"/>\n      <LogLevelLabel>log_level</LogLevelLabel>\n    </Loki>\n~' $f
  sed -i 's/\(<Root.*\)/\1\n      <AppenderRef ref="Loki"\/>/' "$f"
done
```

In stdout of the cluster I see following errors (which I suppose means the jar is somehow not in classpath, or it's looking for wrong class somehow):

```
ERROR Error processing element Loki ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
ERROR Unable to locate appender "Loki" for logger config "root"
```

---

Also tried to add class name to Appender spec:

`<Loki name="Loki" class="pl.tkowalcz.tjahzi.log4j2.LokiAppender" bufferSizeMegabytes="64">`

instead of

`<Loki name="Loki" bufferSizeMegabytes="64">`

Same error.

---

`find /databricks -name '*log4j2-appender-nodep*' -type f` finds nothing.

---

I also tried downloading the jar file put it in dbfs and then install as a JAR library (instead of MAVEN library):

```bash
$ databricks fs cp local/log4j2-appender-nodep-0.9.23.jar dbfs:/Shared/log4j2-appender-nodep-0.9.23.jar
$ databricks libraries install --cluster-id 1-2-345 --jar "dbfs:/Shared/log4j2-appender-nodep-0.9.23.jar"
```

Same error.

---

I'm able to post from teh cluster to Loki intance using `curl`, I can see this log in Grafana GUI:

```bash
ds=$(date +%s%N) && \
echo $ds && \
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -s "http://loki.atops.abc.com:3100/loki/api/v1/push" --data-raw '{"streams": [{ "stream": { "foo": "bar2", "system": "abc" }, "values": [ [ "'$ds'", "'$ds': testing, testing" ] ] }]}'
```

---

This is what the conf file contents after init script: `cat /databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/driver/log4j2.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration monitorInterval="30" status="INFO" packages="pl.tkowalcz.tjahzi.log4j2, com.databricks.logging" shutdownHook="disable">
  <Appenders>
    <Loki name="Loki" bufferSizeMegabytes="64">
      <host>loki.atops.abc.com</host>
      <port>3100</port>

      <ThresholdFilter level="ALL"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%X{tid} [%t] %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n%exception{full}</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>

      <Header name="X-Scope-OrgID" value="ABC"/>
      <Label name="server" value="Databricks"/>
      <Label name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <Label name="system" value="abc"/>

      <LogLevelLabel>log_level</LogLevelLabel>
    </Loki>

    <RollingFile name="publicFile.rolling" fileName="logs/log4j-active.log" filePattern="logs/log4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz" immediateFlush="true" bufferedIO="false" bufferSize="8192" createOnDemand="true">
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
      </Policies>
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n%ex"/>
    </RollingFile>
    
    ---snip---

  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Loki"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="publicFile.rolling.rewrite"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="privateLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="privateFile.rolling.rewrite"/>
    </Logger>
    ---snip---
    
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this happens because log4j is initialized when cluster starts, but libraries that you specify in the Libraries UI - they are installed after cluster starts, so your loki library isn't available during start.

The solution would be to install loki library from the same init script that you use for log4j configuration - just copy library & its dependencies to the `/databricks/jars/` folder (for example from DBFS that will be available to script as `/dbfs/...`).

---

E.g. if you have [uploaded your jar file](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/index.html#interact-with-files-in-cloud-based-object-storage) to `/dbfs/Shared/custom_jars/log4j2-appender-nodep-0.9.23.jar` then add following to the init script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cp /dbfs/Shared/custom_jars/log4j2-appender-nodep-0.9.23.jar /databricks/jars/

# other code to update log4j2.xml etc...
```

Comment: I also added `monitorInterval="30"` and `echo "" > ...` to make testing easier. I can clearly see in logs that log4j2 rereads the config after that library is installed. So far though I installed it via GUI and CLI, will try putting it in `/databricks/jars`